# Unable to Parse the Date, ParseException is thrown

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, parseexception

---

### Unable to parse the given date

```
String DT = "14 Jun 2016 09:54:02 GMT";
DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");           
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(DT);
```

after this I want to convert to CST Time in this format 13-JUN-16 08.53.43

### Exception StackTrace

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-Jun-2016 09:54:02 GMT" at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source) at package2.TimeZone.parseTime(TimeZone.java:16) at package2.TimeZone.main(TimeZone.java:10)
```

Comment: have you tried `joda-time` library to change date time into multiple compatible format as you wish ?? @Hifzur

Comment: please add stackTrace Error and update your question to clarify the Exception cause.

Comment: is Joda-Time in-built of JDK 7? because our project is based on JDK 7!

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-Jun-2016 09:54:02 GMT"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at package2.TimeZone.parseTime(TimeZone.java:16)
at package2.TimeZone.main(TimeZone.java:10)

Comment: `  String DT = "14 Jun 2016 09:54:02 GMT";
    DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    Date dd = simpleDateFormat.parse(DT);
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse(DT).toString());
        //it will print Tue Jun 14 15:24:02 IST 2016
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy HH:mm:ss").format(dd).toString().toUpperCase());
       //it will print 14-JUNE-16 15:24:02`

Comment: thanks @VikrantKashyap

Answer (score 0):

**To parse:**

You are using the wrong mask to parse it, it should be as follows(with MMM instead of MM):

```
DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(DT);
```

**To format it to the desired format:**

```
DateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date).toUpperCase();
```

Without the uppercase it will show 13-jun-16 08.53.43 instead of 13-JUN-16 08.53.43

Comment: Now I got it SCouto, but how to convert it to this output 13-JUN-16 08.53.43. I dont want CST at the end

Comment: done, please, check it out

Comment: I got date in IST format, but I need toconvert it to CST format

Comment: Assuming CST stands for Central Standard Time and not China Standard Time you need to add this line: sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central")); 

(I'll update the answer as well)

Comment: I guess this is what you meant @scouto --> simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));

Comment: IT's indeed the same, but three-letter codes for TimeZones are deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the share @Scouto

Answer (score 0):

Date format should be like as below:

```
String DT = "14 Jun 2016 09:54:02 GMT";
DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss z");           
Date date = (Date) simpleDateFormat.parse(DT);
```

After converting date format, it should pass like below:

```
    String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy HH:mm:ss").format(date).toString().toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(newstring);
```